# Android Button not working?

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to make an app that takes input as feet and inches, and cost per feet, and calculates the cost of rod. It is a pretty simple app,I have done most of the work, but when I click at the calculate `Button`, in place of "result", my answer should come.

**Now here is the XML code:**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/ft"
    android:id="@+id/feet"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/feet1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/feet"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/feet"
    android:inputType="text" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/inches"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/feet"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:inputType="text" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/in"
    android:id="@+id/Inches"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/feet"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/inches"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/inches" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/cost"
    android:id="@+id/cost"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/feet"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/feet"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/feet" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/calcost"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cost"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cost"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cost"
    android:inputType="text" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/cal"
    android:id="@+id/calculate"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cost"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="73dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/ans"
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="123dp" />
```

**And here is the Java code:**

```
package com.example.baqir.saecost;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
public void add(View v)
{
    RelativeLayout rel= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel);
    final TextView result= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
    EditText et1= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.feet1);
    EditText et2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inches);
    EditText ct= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.calcost);
    final double a=Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(et1.getText()));
    final double b=Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(et2.getText()));
    final double c=Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(ct.getText()));
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View g) {
                double i;
                i=(a+(b/12))*c;
            result.setText(i+" Rs");
            }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: Your code looks at the value in the textbox when the activity is created, not when the button is pressed.

Comment: I cant see fromt he code given where you make the call to add()

Comment: plus use the InClickListener of the Button class not of the view class!

Comment: and why dont you do the add() inside the onCreate method?

Answer (score 3):

Change your code like this:

```
public void add(View v)
{
    RelativeLayout rel= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel);
    final TextView result= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
    EditText et1= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.feet1);
    EditText et2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inches);
    EditText ct= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.calcost);
    final double a=Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(et1.getText()));
    final double b=Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(et2.getText()));
    final double c=Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(ct.getText()));
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);
    // button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    //    public void onClick(View g) {
                double i;
                i=(a+(b/12))*c;
            result.setText(i+" Rs");
   //         }
  //  });
}
```

and in your **XML** change add `onClick`, as:

```
<Button
    android:onClick="add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/cal"
    android:id="@+id/calculate"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cost"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="73dp" />
```

Comment: Thanks, it works exactly the way i wanted it to work. But can you tell me, why have u commented that little code in JAVA?  How does my button know when it is clicked and when to set the text, because you have removed the onClickListener. I am beginner, so if you can explain me in a way that I dont need any more help on this topic, that would be really nice of you :)

Comment: Look at the XML file, the "add" function is called whenever the button is clicked. So the entire block of add(View v) function will be executed upon clicking the button.

Answer (score 2):

I got it your issue just add this line in **XML** layout where your `Button` is

```
android:onClick="add"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     RelativeLayout rel= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel);
     final TextView result= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
     EditText et1= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.feet1);
     EditText et2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inches);
     EditText ct= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.calcost);
     final double a=Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(et1.getText()));
     final double b=Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(et2.getText()));
     final double c=Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(ct.getText()));
     final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View g) {
               double i;
               i=(a+(b/12))*c;
               result.setText(i+" Rs");
        }
    });
}
}
```

remove method and write your code in oncreate method.

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.example.baqir.saecost;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RelativeLayout rel= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel);
    final TextView result= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
    EditText et1= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.feet1);
    EditText et2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inches);
    EditText ct= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.calcost);



    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View g) {
          double i;

          final double a=Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(et1.getText()));
          final double b=Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(et2.getText()));
          final double c=Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(ct.getText()));

          i=(a+(b/12))*c;
          result.setText(i+" Rs");
         }
    });

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

As long as the XML files are ok (The IDs are the one you actually used ,not mixed up or anything) ,this should fix your problem.

You were taking the values from the editTexts before pressing the button...so practically, after you wrote anything in there, the code that was grabbing the values, was executed already.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your all views in oncreate method it should work